# Installing HTK for ubuntu - issues with X11

Tags: compiling, makefile

I seem to have some problems with X11 when compiling HTK.

```
Make all
```

give me the error message:

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lX11
```

Looking for it give me :

```
ld -lX11 --verbose



==================================================
attempt to open /usr/x86_64-linux-gnu/lib64/libX11.so failed
attempt to open /usr/x86_64-linux-gnu/lib64/libX11.a failed
attempt to open //usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11.so failed
attempt to open //usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11.a failed
attempt to open //usr/local/lib64/libX11.so failed
attempt to open //usr/local/lib64/libX11.a failed
attempt to open //lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11.so failed
attempt to open //lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11.a failed
attempt to open //lib64/libX11.so failed
attempt to open //lib64/libX11.a failed
attempt to open //usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11.so succeeded
-lX11 (//usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11.so)
libxcb.so.1 needed by //usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11.so
found libxcb.so.1 at //usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb.so.1
libdl.so.2 needed by //usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11.so
found libdl.so.2 at //lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2
libc.so.6 needed by //usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11.so
found libc.so.6 at //lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
libXau.so.6 needed by //usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb.so.1
found libXau.so.6 at //usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXau.so.6
libXdmcp.so.6 needed by //usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb.so.1
found libXdmcp.so.6 at //usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXdmcp.so.6
ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 needed by //lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2
found ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 at //lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
ld: warning: cannot find entry symbol _start; not setting start address
```

I seem to have a version, but I am sure i understand where HTK make is looking for it?...

Somehow i can fix it?

here is the makefile:

```
# ----------------------------------------------------------- 
#                                                             
#                          ___                                
#                       |_| | |_/   SPEECH                    
#                       | | | | \   RECOGNITION               
#                       =========   SOFTWARE                  
#                                                             
#                                                             
# ----------------------------------------------------------- 
#         Copyright: Cambridge University
#          1995-2006 Engineering Department
#                    http://htk.eng.cam.ac.uk
#                    http://mi.eng.cam.ac.uk
#                 
#   Use of this software is governed by a License Agreement   
#    ** See the file License for the Conditions of Use  **    
#    **     This banner notice must not be removed      **    
#                                                             
# ----------------------------------------------------------- 
# File: Makefile.  Generated from Makefile.in by configure.
# ----------------------------------------------------------- 

SHELL = /bin/sh
srcdir = .
top_srcdir = .

prefix = /home/simon/voxforge/bin/htk
exec_prefix = ${prefix}
bindir = ${exec_prefix}/bin
sbindir = ${exec_prefix}/sbin
libexecdir = ${exec_prefix}/libexec
datadir = ${prefix}/share
sysconfdir = ${prefix}/etc
sharedstatedir = ${prefix}/com
localstatedir = ${prefix}/var
libdir = ${exec_prefix}/lib
infodir = ${prefix}/share/info
mandir = ${prefix}/share/man
includedir = ${prefix}/include
oldincludedir = /usr/include

CC = gcc-4.8
CPPFLAGS = 
CFLAGS = $(CPPFLAGS) -m32 -ansi -D_SVID_SOURCE -DOSS_AUDIO -D'ARCH="x86_64"' -Wall -Wno-switch -g -O2
LDFLAGS = -L/usr/X11R6/lib 
LIBS = -lm -lX11 
INSTALL = /usr/bin/install -c

DESTDIR =

pkgdatadir = $(datadir)/@PACKAGE@
pkglibdir = $(libdir)/@PACKAGE@
pkgincludedir = $(includedir)/@PACKAGE@

top_builddir = .

ACLOCAL = @ACLOCAL@
AUTOCONF = @AUTOCONF@
AUTOMAKE = @AUTOMAKE@
AUTOHEADER = @AUTOHEADER@

INSTALL = /usr/bin/install -c
INSTALL_PROGRAM = ${INSTALL} $(AM_INSTALL_PROGRAM_FLAGS)
INSTALL_DATA = ${INSTALL} -m 644
INSTALL_SCRIPT = ${INSTALL}
transform = s,x,x,
MAKEINFO = @MAKEINFO@
PACKAGE = @PACKAGE@
VERSION = @VERSION@

HTKLIB  = HTKLib
HLMLIB  = HLMLib
HTKTOOLS = HTKTools
HLMTOOLS = HLMTools
LVREC = HTKLVRec
HTKBOOK = HTKBook
SUBDIRS = $(HTKLIB) $(HLMLIB) $(HTKTOOLS) $(HLMTOOLS) $(LVREC) $(BOOK) 
ACLOCAL_M4 = $(top_srcdir)/aclocal.m4
mkinstalldirs = $(SHELL) $(top_srcdir)/mkinstalldirs
CONFIG_CLEAN_FILES = 
DIST_COMMON =  README ChangeLog Makefile.am \
Makefile.in aclocal.m4 configure configure.ac install-sh missing \
mkinstalldirs


DISTFILES = $(DIST_COMMON) $(SOURCES) $(HEADERS) $(TEXINFOS) $(EXTRA_DIST)

TAR = gtar
GZIP_ENV = --best

.SUFFIXES:

# build rules
all: htktools hlmtools
$(HTKLIB)/HTKLib.a:
    (cd $(HTKLIB) && $(MAKE) HTKLib.a) \
      || case "$(MFLAGS)" in *k*) fail=yes;; *) exit 1;; esac;
htklib: $(HTKLIB)/HTKLib.a
$(HTKLIB)/HTKLiblv.a:
    (cd $(HTKLIB) && $(MAKE) HTKLiblv.a) \
      || case "$(MFLAGS)" in *k*) fail=yes;; *) exit 1;; esac;
htkliblv: $(HTKLIB)/HTKLiblv.a
$(HLMLIB)/HLMLib.a:
    (cd $(HLMLIB) && $(MAKE) all) \
      || case "$(MFLAGS)" in *k*) fail=yes;; *) exit 1;; esac;
hlmlib: $(HLMLIB)/HLMLib.a
htktools: $(HTKLIB)/HTKLib.a
    (cd $(HTKTOOLS) && $(MAKE) all) \
      || case "$(MFLAGS)" in *k*) fail=yes;; *) exit 1;; esac;
hlmtools: $(HLMLIB)/HLMLib.a
    (cd $(HLMTOOLS) && $(MAKE) all) \
      || case "$(MFLAGS)" in *k*) fail=yes;; *) exit 1;; esac;
hdecode: $(HTKLIB)/HTKLiblv.a
    (cd $(LVREC) && $(MAKE) all) \
      || case "$(MFLAGS)" in *k*) fail=yes;; *) exit 1;; esac;
book: 
    (cd $(HTKBOOK) && $(MAKE) all) \
      || case "$(MFLAGS)" in *k*) fail=yes;; *) exit 1;; esac;

# installation
install-htktools: htktools
    (cd $(HTKTOOLS) && $(MAKE) install) \
    || case "$(MFLAGS)" in *k*) fail=yes;; *) exit 1;; esac;
install-hlmtools: hlmtools
    (cd $(HLMTOOLS) && $(MAKE) install) \
    || case "$(MFLAGS)" in *k*) fail=yes;; *) exit 1;; esac;
install-hdecode:
    (cd $(LVREC) && $(MAKE) install) \
    || case "$(MFLAGS)" in *k*) fail=yes;; *) exit 1;; esac;
install-book: book
    (cd $(HTKBOOK) && $(MAKE) install) \
    || case "$(MFLAGS)" in *k*) fail=yes;; *) exit 1;; esac;

clean:
    /bin/rm -f *~
    @for dir in $(SUBDIRS); do \
      (cd $$dir && $(MAKE) clean) \
      || case "$(MFLAGS)" in *k*) fail=yes;; *) exit 1;; esac; \
    done && test -z "$$fail"
distclean: clean
    /bin/rm -f Makefile config.h config.status config.cache config.log
    @for dir in $(SUBDIRS); do \
      (cd $$dir && $(MAKE) distclean) \
      || case "$(MFLAGS)" in *k*) fail=yes;; *) exit 1;; esac; \
    done && test -z "$$fail"

install: install-htktools install-hlmtools
docs: book

.PHONY: all doc install clean distclean htklib-decode \
    htktools hlmtools hdecode docs book \
    install-htktools install-hlmtools install-hdecode install-book
```

Comment: No issues with x11 : »» attempt to open //usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11.so **succeeded** ««

Comment: @KnudLarsen You are right.. It does find it, but `make` is still not able to find it.. I guess my question is more precise where is the makefile is looking for it, as then I could make a softlink to that position with the one which was succeeded.

Comment: You can always do e.g. `cd  /usr/local/lib64` or `cd  /usr/local/lib` ; `ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11.so` . Easy to find and delete when not required any more.